# System audio in Quartz Composer

Tags: macos, audio, quartz-composer

I am building a music visualizer in Quartz Composer, and it works just fine. The problem is that the audio input is through a microphone, so any noise that I make while its running displays.

What I want it to do is take only the sound that is running digitally through the system. Not a line input, but whats running through the Mixer AU for output in the system. I haven't found any way to do this except for WireTap, but I don't want a demo and I can't currently afford the full version.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This probably belongs over in avp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Cycling 74's [Soundflower](http://cycling74.com/products/soundflower/) to route audio between applications.

You might also want to check out [Kineme AudioTools](https://kineme.net/AudioTools), which provides more analysis capability than QC's built-in `Audio Input` patch.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't seem to configure Itunes to run through SoundFlower...Any help?

Comment: Under System Preferences > Sound > Output, you can choose Soundflower as the default system output device — this will affect sound output from iTunes.